# Error trying to read from an sqlite file (Logcat : SQLiteException)

Tags: android, sqlite

I've created an sqlite file , and placed in the projects directory. It's still empty but I ran my program to see if it even works - and it doesn't (I've written a certain Log as an indication).
Here's the code of the SQLiteOpenHelper subclass . Thank you very much.

```
import java.util.Map;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

class DatabaseLoader extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static DatabaseLoader instance;
    private Map<String,Password> passwords ;
    private static final String ERROR_OPEN_FILE_TAG = "Error Opening File";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "passwords.sql";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static synchronized DatabaseLoader getInstance( Context context ) 
    {
        if (instance == null) 
        {
          instance = new DatabaseLoader( context.getApplicationContext() );
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private DatabaseLoader( Context context ) {
        super( context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );
    }

    public Map<String,Password> loadDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor result =  db.rawQuery( "select * from passwords", null );
            result.moveToFirst();

            while( !result.isAfterLast() )
            {
                String password = result.getString( 1 );
                int date = result.getInt( 2 );
                passwords.put( password , new Password( password, date) );
                result.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        catch( SQLiteException errorOpeningDB )
        {
            Log.d( ERROR_OPEN_FILE_TAG, "SQLiteException - error opening db for writing" );
        }

        return passwords;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase db )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the Log message ,stating that getWritableDatabse threw me an exception since it couldn't open the file .

Comment: Please, add the logcat to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your `SQLite Database` file into `Assets` and use this code

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static final String DB_NAME = "DBNAME.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
 * access to the application assets and resources.
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + File.separator
            + "databases" + File.separator;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
        // Toast.makeText(myContext, "already exist",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        // Toast.makeText(myContext, "already exist",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
        // Toast.makeText(myContext, "not already exist",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    // transfer bytes from the Input file to the output file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

// Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the
// database.
// You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd
// be easy
// to you to create adapters for your views.
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem !!!!!

Comment: why is the db extension .db and not .sqlt ?

Comment: @BVtp You can use .sqlite extension, but mostly developers use .db extension thats why I use this.

Comment: alright, thank you.
I've got a certain problem with it though. It does create a file in data/.. dir but it doesn't have a table. i.e , it just creates a file but doesn't copy the content.

Comment: @BVtp You have to add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest for this

Answer (score 0):

Embedding a database within your app is generally a bad idea. If you decide to do so anyway, you need to copy the database from the application assets folder to the data folder on first launch before you can open it for writing.

It's probably easier to create the database from scratch in the app, especially if it's empty.

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily be 'easier' in my case,since I have 10k records in my db.
My goal is to initialize the database with all the records.Then,the first time a user open the app a the subclass of Helper will load this db and pass to a certain class which will manage everything.
Then check with the server if there's any new updates.
So , instead of doing "insert" 10k times to initialize the database,I want to do this:
JSONObject with all the values. I will write a code to pass all its content to the empty database file and then I'll use this db file as default everytime a user opens the app.

Comment: I got the part about the 10,000 records you don't want to insert and you're right, if the 10,000 records never change it's easier to have the DB already initialized. I don't get the purpose of the JSONObject though. Anyway in order to use an embedded DB you need to copy it from the assets to the application data folder first.